# Origin of the term "top tucker"

Tags: etymology, subcontinental-english, foreign-phrases

In India, at least in the Southern part, there is a phrase "Top tucker" used to compliment/attribute someone for their exceptional qualities/achievements in a colloquial way.

The entry Tucker in OED says:

> Noun
>   1. *historical* A piece of lace or linen worn in or around the top of a bodice or as an insert at the front of a low-cut dress
>   
> [ Early 19th century: derivative of British English slang tuck 'consume food or drink']
>   
> 2. [mass noun] Australian /NZ informal
>   
> Food
>
> Verb
>   [with object] (usually be tuckered out) North American informal
>   Exhaust; wear out

And etymonline.com points tukere to the origin but I am clueless on what tukere meant/was. [Google](http://www.google.com/q=tukere) didn't show up any relevant results...

> **tucker(n.)**
>   "piece of lace worn around the neck," 1680s, agent noun from tuck
>   (v.). In Middle English tukere was "one who dresses or finishes
>   cloth," hence the surname.
>
> **tucker(v.)**
>   "to tire, weary," 1833, New England slang, of uncertain origin, perhaps from >tucked (past participle of tuck (v.)), which had, in reference to dogs, a >slang sense of "exhausted, underfed." Especially with out. Related: >Tuckered; tuckering.

And a search for top tucker brought up an [old TV show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXMfjacoWWA) titled `Top Tucker` starring a famous comedian portrayed as an ignorant rural youngster who later develops himself to cope up with the cunning environment and hence the title Top Tucker I believe. No other comments/reviews of this show either...

This was all I could get my hands on and I hope this is not off topic or too specific to ask for the ***origin of this peculiar usage of the phrase***. My bets are on tucker which probably was common to indicate rich/high class individuals and this found its way to Indian languages during British colonisation as was the case with many other words commonly used every day...

---

### Updates

I was editing my post to add few (major) points I missed and while I was at it, I thought could compile few (mis?)leads from comments to make it easier for new visitors.

**From Comments to the post:** 
Apparently it is also prevalent in parts of US in context of food, features in a famous Australian song(*tucker*-bag: a bag to carry food) "[Waltzing Matilda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltzing_Matilda)", "Top tucker" was used in context of exclamation by Charles Hamilton a.k.a Frank Richards in his novels. Also, *Tucker* Car Corporation headed by Preston *Tucker* was famous in the US after WWII.

**History&Genealogy**
Interestingly the [*Tuckers*](http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~bmuwgw/tuckergen.htm) native to Great Britain, held key positions that influenced India during British East India company and the British Crown, [Josiah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Tucker)(protested against the British East India company), [Frederick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Booth-Tucker) (Top official in Salvation army, worked with several criminal tribes to reform them) , and [Henry St George](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_St_George_Tucker#Career)(look into his link) to name a few I suspect would have impacted the Indians.

Last update, a [survey](https://plus.google.com/111446439968456281635/posts/6RSUuBKeLu6) for "top tucker" I posted on G+ isn't making any progress :P

Hope this helps.

Comment: Pretty sure that "top tucker" is an Australianism for; very good food/meal.

Comment: Yeah? but google didn't light up those possibilities.... But, OED says something similar but not top tucker...

Comment: +1 for a very well researched and well documented question. I agree that you are likely on the right track. It's worth noting that *tucker* can also mean food, as illustrated in the famous Australian song "Waltzing Matilda" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltzing_Matilda)). But I'm not sure that is going to lead to your answer.

Comment: Thanks @Nonnal, didn't want my first post on EL&U down voted or closed as off-topic...

Comment: But, @JoeDark 's version of Top tucker is very good meal, may be it could be used in the context "you're some _good stuff_". But, I am looking for more than conjectures.

Comment: I'm interested in the South Indian roots here. This must be a feature of the British Raj, but who did it refer to? Bureaucrats? Local cricket teams? Who would have been habitually wearing some neckcloth decoration at that time?

Comment: @JohnLawler I had the same intuition. Local cricket teams? I am not sure if we should be suspecting them. I checked on [attire of a typical British Lord in court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_dress#India) but there were no indications of neck clothing, except for Capes and Bow ties if they count...

Comment: JohnLawler I think it refers to food rather than neck-wear.  Tuck and tucker are old-fashioned slang for food - still current in Australia. It was typical in the speech of public schoolboys (i.e. private school) up to about the 1950s (from when I remember it). It is found extensively in the works of Frank Richards author of the books on the school Greyfriars, whose most celebrated character was Billy Bunter. But I believe top tucker is a kind of exclamation - not necessarily connected to food - a bit like top drawer, top hole old boy. It is just the sort of thing you find in India.

Comment: Yeah, in parts of the US "top tucker" would mean "good food".  (In other parts you'd simply get dumb looks.)

Comment: @HotLicks But the way I'm imagining it being used has no real connection to food anymore. Consider *I say my old chap's just bought me an Aston Martin*. *Oh - top tucker old boy*.

Comment: Of course, "Tucker" was the name of a short-lived US automobile company, after WWII.  So mentioning "tucker" in connection with an automobile (especially an old or "classic" one) is apt to lead to even further confusion.

Comment: @HotLicks Licks how come google never returned these results? at least not on the first two pages. So, "top tucker" might also stem from a classic automobile!! But, they are after WWII, how could they have seeped into Indian soil?

Comment: @WS2 what does it imply? A rich kid or a lucky one? or just referring to the fine automobiles again?

Comment: @Andrew My comment was highly speculative. *Tucker* certainly involved food, and still does in Australia. I was simply saying that it was an expression used in British public (private) schools by posh young gentlemen. And I could have imagined *top tucker* being a response to any item of good news - but I have never heard it used in that way.

Comment: @WS2 Yeah, a lot of hits from Aboriginal Australian's sources of diet. When I used the [google books search](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=top+tucker) for _Top tucker_ I got a relevant hit _Top End Tucker_  an account on Aboriginal food.

Comment: @Andrew - I'm simply saying that "top tucker" is not a well-known expression in the US, so a listener/reader is apt to cast about for some apparent reference.  "Tucker" the food and "Tucker" the automobile would be more familiar to many/most Americans.

Comment: Thanks for including the research but a better approach for searching is adding the relevant keywords in your search. For example, instead of searching just "top tucker", you can search "[top tucker origin](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=top+tucker+origin)". Also, *OED* has the definition for Australian slang term *tucker* meaning food.

Comment: Additionally, when I check Google books, the term *top tucker* is used for good food (in the books related to Australia): https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22top+tucker%22+slang+dictionary#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22top+tucker%22+food

Comment: @ermanen yes, I did try searching for "top tucker" + _origin_ or _etymology_ but nothing showed up for the whole phrase! I got to read about origins of `Tucker` from several sources though.

Comment: @ermanen now that you mentioned  _OED_, yeah, I missed it while looking for similar meanings from _etymonline_. Is it too late to edit & update my post?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, you can always add additional info. It is never late. And I thought you didn't search "[top tucker origin](https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=top+tucker+origin)" because you said you couldn't find the info people mentioned. The history of "tucker" from phrases.org.uk and the car brand Tucker is in the first page result.

Comment: @ermanen post updated and thanks for pointing out the sources, I shouldn't have jumped the gun...

Answer (score 1):

Tucker and especially the expression "best bib and tucker" refer to high society clothes from the 18th century. Tuckers continued to be worn  till the late 19th century. The term and the expression may well have entered into contact with the Indian context during the British colonial period. The following extract offers an interesting account  on its usage and shows that the reference to food has no connection to clothes:

***[Best bib and tucker](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/best-bib-and-tucker.html):***

> - This term originated not in any figurative sense but literally - both ***bibs and tuckers were items of women's clothing from the 17th to late 19th centuries.***
> - Early bibs were somewhat like modern day bibs, although they weren't specifically used to protect clothes from spilled food as they are now.
> - ***Tuckers were lace pieces fitted over the bodice, sometimes called 'pinners' or 'modesty pieces'.***  These were known by the late 17th century and were described by Randle Holme in The Academy of Armory, or a Storehouse of Armory and Blazon, 1688:
>
>   - *"A Pinner or Tucker, is a narrow piece of Cloth - which compasseth the top of a Womans Gown about the Neck part."*[image]
> - Tuckers, as the name suggests, were originally tucked in. Pinners differed by being pinned rather than tucked. Pinner is clearly the precursor of pinafore - originally pin-a-fore, that is, pinned on the front.
>
>   - *Incidentally, the blazons of the title of Holme's book gave the name to another form of dress - the blazer. Blazons were the heraldic coats of arms or badges of office worn by the king's messenger. Blazer jackets, which became fashionable in the early 20th century as uniforms for supporters of sports teams and as school uniforms, mimicked the heraldic style.* [image]
> - ***'Best bib and tucker' is an 18th century term,*** the first known citation of which is from a translation of the Marquis d'Argens' ambitiously titled work New Memoirs establishing a True Knowledge of Mankind, 1747:
>
>   - *"The Country-woman minds nothing on Sundays so much as her best Bib and Tucker."*
> - Tuckers continued to be worn until the late 19th century. Charlotte Bronte referred to the practice in Jane Eyre, 1847:
>
>   - *"Some of the girls have two clean tuckers in the week; the rules limit them to one."*

***Tucker meaning food***:

> - 'Tuck' is a slang term for food which was coined in English public schools in the 19th century; for example, Thomas Hughes' Tom Brown's School Days, 1857:
>
>   - *"The Slogger looks rather sodden, as if he didn't take much exercise and ate too much tuck."*
> - ***This migrated to Australia, where it was modified to 'tucker'***. Both this meaning of tucker and the women's bib meaning have connections with food and it is tempting to speculate that they are in some way connected. It seems that they aren't. ***Tucker in the food sense derives from the earlier term 'a tuck-out' (later also 'tuck-in'), which meant 'a hearty meal'.*** 'Tuck-out' was synonymous with 'blow-out'. Both terms are listed in John Badcock's Slang: A Dictionary of the Turf, 1823:
>
>   - *Blow-out - a good dinner will blow-out a man's tripes like any thing; so will a heavy supper. Either, or any other gormandising meal, is also 'a famous tuck-out'.*
> - 'Blow-out', which appears to have had quite a crude meaning, is a long way removed from the protective crinoline bibs worn by Jane Austen heroines.
> - Another link that is sometimes made is the possible connection between tucker and tuxedo. The two names sound similar of course and the cummerbund that is usually worn with the formal tuxedo suit is rather like a tucker. There's no foundation to that notion. Tuxedos are named from Tuxedo Park, New York, where they were first worn in 1886.

(The Phrase Finder)

Comment: Interesting I couldn't find any of the references you've provided by myself, I'll add the phrase finder to my toolbox, thank you! But there is no concrete evidence of tucker(context of meal) playing a role in India and no evidence of tuckers(neck ware) leading to this phrase/slang...

Comment: I found a new lead in this quest, a family of [Tuckers](http://www.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~bmuwgw/tuckergen.htm) from UK who have held dignitary offices in the Indian British empire. I am guessing, `Preston Tucker`, who conceived the _Tucker 48_ was in this chain of genealogy(no evidence) and [Josiah Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Tucker) popular for his stand against the British East India Company and influenced [freedom of the USA](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1FqkCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT61&lpg=PT61&dq=British+Visions+of+America,+1775-1820:+Republican+Realities+Josiah+Tucker)

Comment: @Andrew -          That's another interesting trail, but is there any reference to 'top trucker' being used the way you are suggesting?

Comment: none so far... But there are few influential people from the Tucker genealogy who made their marks in India, [Henry Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_St_George_Tucker) (Chairman), [Frederick Booth Tucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Booth-Tucker) (Salvation Army) held significant roles in the British East India Company. The latter Tucker worked with Indian tribes and criminology in the early 1900s and has certainly been known to reform a lot of violent Indian castes and tribes. This was as far as I could get...

Comment: I am actually referring to the 'Indian  usage'  reference.

Comment: Yeah, the _Tucker_s I suggested were in key positions to influence the society and this could(no references) have lead to "Top Tucker" in the context _great_ Tucker. This is just my hypothesis, I'm compiling a survey in G+ to check if this is still a prevailing slang.